# How should I use rails and simple_form for nested resources?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, nested-attributes, fields-for, strong-parameters

I'm trying to create one resource with another nested resource at the same time. I'm using Rails4 and simple_form 3.0.0rc. Here is my code.

## Models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile
end

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

## Controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
    @user.build_profile
  end

  def create
    user = User.new user_params
    user.save
    redirect_to root_url
#    @par =params
  end

  private
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:email, profile_attributes: [:name])
    end
end
```

## View (form for new user)

```
<%= simple_form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :email %>
  <%= simple_fields_for :profile do |p| %>
    <%= p.input :name %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

When I submit the form, the `create` action receives this `params`:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
"authenticity_token"=>"dJAcMcdZnrtTXVIeS2cNBwM+S6dZh7EQEALZx09l8fg=", 
"user"=>{"email"=>"vasily.sib@gmail.com"},
"profile"=>{"name"=>"Vasily"},
"commit"=>"Create User",
"action"=>"create",
"controller"=>"users"}
```

And after calling `user_params` the only thing that left is

```
{"email"=>"vasily.sib@gmail.com"}
```

And, as you can see, there is nothing about `profile`, so no profile will be created.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use `f.simple_fields_for` instead of `simple_fields_for`:

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :profile do |p| %>
    <%= p.input :name %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This literally saved me hours.

Comment: LOL, I was scratching my head real hard. Thanks. So obvious, don't know why thought it'd be different with simple_form xD

Answer (score 3):

In my case I had the object "book" which belongs to "tour" and "tour" has_many "books".

In the "BookController" in the method "new" I find the tour and initialize the book object:

`@tour = Tour.find(params[:tour_id])`

```
@book = Book.new
```

This is the partial form to create a book: _form.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for [@tour, @book] do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name, label: "Name"%>
  <%= f.input :NoReservations, label: "Number of Reservations" %>
  <%= f.input :email, label: "Email" %>
  <h3>Num of available places</h3>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```