# ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in JobsController#creat and want to populate the company name automatically

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I was create a Job, it will show this error when using `belongs_to :company` in the Job class. I want to populate the company name automatically in the _form input, how should i do that,(i want to show it view/jobs/_form.html.erb)

Why am I getting this error?

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in JobsController#create
Company(#153084460) expected, got "VIrtusa Corperation-" which is an instance of String(#9740380)

    # Migrations
    class CreateJobs < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
      def change
        create_table :jobs do |t|
          t.string :title
          t.text :description
          t.string :company
          t.integer :user_id
          t.timestamps
        end
      end
    end

    class CreateCompanies < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
      def change
        create_table :companies do |t|
          t.string :c_name
          t.text :c_description
          t.integer:user_id
          t.timestamps
        end
      end
    end

    # Models
    class User < ApplicationRecord
      # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
      # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
      devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
             :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

      has_many :companies
      has_many :jobs
    end

    class Job < ApplicationRecord
        belongs_to :user
        belongs_to :category
        belongs_to :company
    end

    class Company < ApplicationRecord
        belongs_to:user
        has_many:jobs

    end

    # Jobs controller
    def show
            end

            def new

                   @job = current_user.jobs.build       
            end

    def create
        @job = current_user.jobs.build(jobs_params)

          if @job.save
            flash[:success]= "success"
            redirect_to @job

            else

            flash[:error]=@job.errors.full_messages
            render "new"
            end
        end

    def jobs_params
                params.require(:job).permit(:title, :description, :company, :category_id, :image,:jobclosedate)
    end
```

Views/jobs/_form file

```
<%= simple_form_for(@job,validation:true ,html: { mutlipart: true, class: 'form-horizontal'}) do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :title, label: "Job Title", input_html: { class: "form-control"}%>
    <%= f.input :description, label: "Job Description", input_html: { class: "form-control" }%>
    <%= f.input :company, label: "Your Company", input_html: { class: "form-control" }%>
    <%= f.collection_select :category_id,Category.all, :id, :name, {promt: "Choose a category" }%>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted params should be company_id and not company.

Your migrations don’t include a relation between companies and jobs. In jobs you should have a reference to a company (a company_id and not a name)

You must pass the company_id (it seems you are passing the name)

Answer (score 0):

I think this error happened because `company` in `jobs_params` is a String. I assume this meaning of this attribute is company name. There are 2 solutions to fix:

1 - Using `company_id` instead of `company` to request to the controller

2 - Look up corresponding company in `create`

```
def create
  job_attrs = jobs_params.except(:company)
  job_attrs[:company] = Company.find_by(c_name: jobs_params[:company])

  @job = current_user.jobs.build(job_attrs)

  if @job.save
    flash[:success]= "success"
    redirect_to @job

  else

    flash[:error]=@job.errors.full_messages
    render "new"
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks a lot ,i used corresponding to company, now that's having error, C:/Users/Anuradha-PC/Desktop/Ruby/Jobs_board2/app/controllers/jobs_controller.rb:24: syntax error, unexpected ',' ...any] = Company.find_by(c_name:, job_params [:company]) ... ^ C:/Users/Anuradha-PC/Desktop/Ruby/Jobs_board2/app/controllers/jobs_controller.rb:24: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end
Extracted source (around line #24):
           
  def create
   job_attrs = job_params.except(:company)
   job_attrs[:company] = Company.find_by(c_name:, job_params [:company])

Comment: I think that you not copy exact the code. There is `:,` `Company.find_by(c_name:, job_params [:company])` which cause the error. Please try again with the new code, I also have changed  `job_params` to `jobs_params`.

Comment: thanks , but still have a another issue , ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError in JobsController#create
can't write unknown attribute `company_id`
Extracted source (around line #27):  

   @job = current_user.jobs.build(job_attrs)

   if @job.save
    flash[:success]= "success"

Comment: Got your issue. You should change your `jobs` table to use `company_id` instead of `company` to make the association on model work.

Comment: thanks It's working now, but i want to populate the company name automatically in the _form input, how should i do that

Comment: I think that you should post other question or add the view in the this question. Hence, I can suggest the solution.

Comment: I don't see that.

Comment: check it now, otherwise i will post new question

Comment: I compared the diff of you change 8 mins ago but I don't see you post the view where you need to use company name.

Comment: thanks a lot, ,i want automatically popualate the company in the  view/jobs/_form.html.erb

Comment: Try to implement as this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18436777/how-should-i-use-rails-and-simple-form-for-nested-resources

Comment: i try to do that, but still having this issue, it's says Company must exist

Comment: You should post another question so the other ones can take a look.